# Ruby: function (appears to) return correct value but fails rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, return-value, specifications

Here's the spec:

```
it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be_false
end
```

Here's my method:

```
def include?(k)
  @entries.each_key do |n|
    if (n==k)
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

If I do, say:

```
puts myd.include?('fish')
```

console prints false (correctly)

But the spec fails with:

```
Failure/Error: @d.include?('fish').should be_false
expected false to respond to `false?`
```

And I do not know why. Been working on this for a day now and completely stumped...

Here's the whole thing:

```
class Dictionary
  attr_accessor :entries, :keywords

  def initialize
    @entries={}
  end

  def add(entry)
    if entry.class==Hash
      @entries.merge!(entry)
    elsif entry.class==String
      h={entry => nil}
      @entries.merge!(h)
    end
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys.sort
  end

  def include?(k)
    @entries.each_key do |n|
      if (n==k)
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end


  def find(term)
    results={}
    @entries.each_key do |n|
      if (n.include? term)
        results.merge!(n => @entries[n])
      end
    end
    if (results.length)
      return results
    end
    return false
  end

  def printable
    str=""
    sortedentries = @entries.sort_by { |k, v| k}
    str=sortedentries.map{ |k, v| "[#{k}] \"#{v}\"\n" }.join
    return str
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rspec's magic method is biting you here. The hint is in the error:

```
expected false to respond to `false?
```

If the thing you are testing does not have a method `false?` you cannot run `be_false`. e.g. `nil.nil?` can be ran, so then `nil.should be_nil` is a valid test. But `nil.admin?` is not runnable, hence `nil.should be_admin` is not a valid test.

Instead of `should be_false` consider using `should equal false`.

Comment: thank you very much. i knew the answer was in "false to respond to `false?`"

a follow-up if i may? changing the `should be_false` to `should equal false` but changing the spec to fit my code feels 'wrong.

how can i make the change in my code to meet the spec?

Comment: The spec is stupid. Why do you want to meet it? Anyway, if you *do* want to meet it, the failure message tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: thank you for your comment. the spec may be stupid but this is an assignment and the assignment is to meet the spec.

while i appreciate your comments, if i knew what to do, i would have done it and we'd not be having this conversation. can you help me understand what to return to meet the `should be_false` condition.

Comment: "but changing the spec to fit my code feels 'wrong. how can i make the change in my code to meet the spec?" Not sure if I'm following you there. You prefer to have a `.false?` so you can use `.be_false`? Or do you want to introduce a `.be_false`?

Comment: hey berkes. what i mean is, what would i return in include?() to meet the rspec .be_false? and .be_true? conditions (if 'false' and 'true' are not correct)?

i guess what i am struggling to understand is why 'false' doesn't satisfy the .be_false? condition. make sense?

Comment: The error message says "expected `false` to respond to `false?`". What is unclear about that? You need to make `false`respond  to the method call `false?`.